# Geotools: Set custom primary key

Tags: java, geotools, dbf

I have a script which reload data from dbf file and create a new table in postgres database using geotools plugin.
My problem is when geotools reload fields name from the file it adds a new field **fid** to make it as a primary key(by default).

PS: my file fields does not contain a field name **fid**,
My fields are(field1, field2)

I dont want to use the default primary key, i want to set my custom one from the my fields list.
please find below my script which work perfectly except the primary key issue .
Could you please help me.

```
    public static void importDBFFileToPostgreSQL(Path filepath, String tablename) {
    DataStore pgDatastore = postgisDataStore.getInstance();
    DbaseFileReader dbaseFileReader = null;
    try {
        try (FileChannel in = FileChannel.open(filepath)) {
            dbaseFileReader = new DbaseFileReader(in, true, Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1"));
        }
        DbaseFileHeader header = dbaseFileReader.getHeader();
        List<AttributeDescriptor> attributes = buildAttributesFromDBFHeader(header);

        // create the feature type
        SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder simpleFeatureTypeBuilder = new SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder();
        simpleFeatureTypeBuilder.setName(tablename);
        simpleFeatureTypeBuilder.addAll(attributes);

        SimpleFeatureType newtype = simpleFeatureTypeBuilder.buildFeatureType();
        pgDatastore.createSchema(newtype);
    }}
```

Comment: where do you set the new FID? That code just sets up the table.

Comment: the fid column is set automatically when it creates the schema pgDatastore.createSchema(newtype); i think because that i didn't mention the primary key which is my problem

Comment: If you look in the newType you will see the FID defined (it's mandatory in the SF spec)

Answer (score 1):

The GeoTools `gt-jdbc` module defines this behaviour and will always add a [serial integer](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/master/modules/library/jdbc/src/main/java/org/geotools/jdbc/JDBCDataStore.java#L3152) [fid column](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/master/modules/library/jdbc/src/main/java/org/geotools/jdbc/JDBCDataStore.java#L2376) as your primary key for any table it creates.

The best way to generate fids in the way you want is to use a "virtual table" (or view) like this:

```
VirtualTable vt = new VirtualTable(tableName + "_v",
    "select * from " + tableName);
List<String> prime = new ArrayList<>();
prime.add("STATE_ABBR");
prime.add("STATE_FIPS");
vt.setPrimaryKeyColumns(prime);

JDBCDataStore jdbcDataStore = (JDBCDataStore) dataStore;
jdbcDataStore.createVirtualTable(vt);
```

Though you still end up with a fid like `fid id=states_v.TN.47`.